# how to retrieve image from rest web service with json

Tags: java

This my web service DB operation, if i comment blob field line means it works fine.i getting json string.but i want to take tat image to my jsp page. how can i achieve this?

```
     @GET
        @Produces("application/json")
        @Path("/")
        public  String getJson(@QueryParam("appno") int appno) {
        app_be.setCus_first_name( rs.getString("cus_first_name"));
                app_be.setCus_last_name(rs.getString("cus_last_name"));
                app_be.setApplication_num(rs.getInt("aplication_num"));
                app_be.setResi_address(rs.getString("resi_address"));
                app_be.setWork_place_address(rs.getString("work_place_address"));
                app_be.setRenewaldate(rs.getDate("app_date"));
                app_be.setProfession(rs.getString("profession"));
                app_be.setPhoto(rs.getBlob("photo"));
                app_be.setPhone_number(rs.getString("phone_number"));
                app_be.setMobile_num(rs.getString("mobile_num"));
                app_be.setMembership_type(rs.getString("membership_type"));
                app_be.setMembership_cycle(rs.getString("membership_cycle"));
                app_be.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));
                app_be.setDueamt("1002");
                app_be.setDesignation("designation");
                app_be.setDebitbal("100022");
                app_be.setCreditlimit("credilimt");
                 app_be.setAge(rs.getInt("age"));
                 app_be.setSex(rs.getString("sex"));
                  }
                  ObjectWriter ow = new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
            String json = ow.writeValueAsString(app_be);
retrun json;
```

this last line give json string in this conversion blob field is not included means it convert and giving json string,otherwise it showing error, because objectwriter cant write blob as json string so please give idea to take my image to my jsp or servlet from this restful webservice. please help.

Comment: I am confused. What are you trying to do?

Comment: i want to take image from my db to jsp.im using restful webservice wth json.

Answer (score 2):

Load the image separately, change the `src` attribute of the image to an URL that points to a servlet that returns the image correctly.

Comment: this is webservice then how can i point servlet from here.can you help me with code please

Comment: Forget about loading the image with JSON or webservice into a webpage. Just create a plain servlet that returns the image wanted (plenty of examples out there); pass the table id as parameter in the `src` attribute of the `img` tag in your page (through JS).

Answer (score 0):

refactor and return the url of the image, not a serialized form of the image. Then the url ca be referenced in your jsp.